# jQuery Validation plugin's method throws error when called on empty collection

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

[jQuery plugin's Validation's](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) method `Valid()` throws an error `this[0] is undefined` when called on empty collection. I thought jQuery convention is not to do anything on empty collection, certainly not throw any error or may be I am missing something. Could someone shed light on it please?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J5r4X/2)

Code fragment from the plugin. this[0] - shown below - throws the error as the collection is empty.

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid
valid: function() {
    if ( $(this[0]).is('form')) {
        return this.validate().form();
    } else {
        var valid = true;
        var validator = $(this[0].form).validate(); // This is the line that throws error
        this.each(function() {
            valid &= validator.element(this);
        });
        return valid;
    }
```

Comment: Are we supposed to check the collection before calling a method on them? I thought we don't have to. I updated the code to include call of addClass which doesn't throw any error even when called on empty collection. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I do is just add class to inputs that i want to have validate then my form has an id and i call validate to it

```
  $("#myform").validate()
```

here is one [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/xmcn6/) of how i use form validation

i also recommend looking at the [demos](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

generally speaking of standard jquery if you apply say like a click event to an element that doesn't exist you don't get errors jquery skips over it. that said maybe validate should do the same but it apparently does not so I would suggest doing it the way I posted or check for the length of the selector before applying validate

Comment: The demo is just a tiny piece of code where I got this error. I have a rather complex form and in certain situation I don't want to validate the whole form but just a field. Also the point of this question is not really to solve this specific problem but to know if this is something that needs to be taken care of in other places as well. There are multiple places where things like $("someSelector").someMethod is done. Should all those places be revisited?